# Shared Session Across Domains

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

Okay.. I have two domains example.com and example.net, they share the same code space and sessions. The problem is that the domain is supposed to change when the user changes the language, when this happens all the session data is lost. I want to do an ajax call right before that so I can change the session.
Here is the code which is used to initialize the session.

```
<?php 
    /* This method is invoked */
    public function start($session_id = '', $key = 'default') {
        if (!session_id()) {
            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'Off');
            ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
            ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 'On');

            if ($session_id) {
                session_id($session_id);
            }   

            if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\-]{22,52}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
                exit('Error: Invalid session ID!');
            }

            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
            session_start();
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = array();
        }

        $this->data =& $_SESSION[$key]; 

        return true;            
    }
```

I tried creating a standalone script to handle the ajax call, but It failed to work.

```
<?php 
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'Off');
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
    ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
    ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 'On');


    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
    session_start();
    session_id($_POST['session_id']);


    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $data = array('session_id' => session_id());
    echo json_encode($data);
```

The session is not preserved when switching between the two domains.
Any clues?

Comment: Are the domains all subdomains of the same domain? Put the containing domain in the `session_set_cookie_params()` call.

Comment: Disabling ```session.use_only_cookies``` is dangerous!

Comment: @Barmar No, they are not subdomains. They are 2 different domains - example.com and example.net.

Comment: Then you're probably screwed. Cookies can't be shared between different domains. Do you really have to use different domains, can't you make a redirect from `example.fr` to `fr.example.com`?

Comment: No, I cant use subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security feature of web browsers - a session uses a cookie that is attached to a domain, and the browser will not send this cookie to another domain.

As you control both domains, you can achieve this by including auth information in the URL. This is a complicated topic. You could homebrew something that would work, but if you aren't familiar with the security problems you would be better using an off the shelf single sign on solution.

Comment: While I completely agree with your answer, especially the part with SSO - sadly, there's no SSO solution that's.. actually good, easy and out of the box. I wish there were, but SimpleSamlPHP - ultra crap, should be burned with fire and acid. Auth0, PingIdentity, Okta - neither easy, nor free. There are libraries for creating your own solution (LightSaml) but all of this implies that the developer understands the SSO protocols. In this particular instance, it's probably easier to share a cookie between domains. It's not the most elegant solution. but we're not talking enterprise app here.

Comment: @N.B. Certainly easier conceptually, but it falls down on reliability - you need everybody's browser to play ball I'd go with a custom auth token in the URL but that's a blog post, not an SO answer.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way that I can send the session_id over to another domain and hijack the session there?

Comment: @nikksan That's correct. You need to look at SSO or roll your own, via token passing in the URL. It might be worth arguing back about having the separate domain.

Comment: @SimonBrahan in our application we dont require users to be logged in order to use it, which eliminates SSO as a possible solution.

Comment: OK. What are you storing in the session?